# Combobox SelectedValue isn't working?

Tags: c#, combobox, microsoft-metro

I have created a combobox in xaml like this:

```
ComboBox x:Name="cbTest" SelectedValue="{Binding TestSpeed}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,10,0,0" Width="250" SelectionChanged="cbTest_SelectionChanged"/>
```

And the Combobox is filled with the following items:

```
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
            cbTest.Items.Add(i);
```

I see the items in the combobox, but it doesn't show the SelectedValue what I choose before. This is the property:

```
private short _testSpeed;
public short TestSpeed
{
    get
    {
        return _testSpeed;
    }
    set
    {
        _testSpeed= value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

And this is when I change the item on SelectedChanged

```
 _vm.TestSpeed = (short)Convert.ToInt16(cbTest.SelectedValue);
```

TestSpeed gives me the correct data in debug, but the selectedValue binding isn't working!?

Comment: "I see the items in the combobox, but it doesn't show the SelectedValue what I choose before." - Are you selecting this in code or in the properties for the code?  Do you mean a default 'SelectedValue'?

Comment: Hi @Brian, the binding "SelectedValue="{Binding TestSpeed"} should get the "TestSpeed" property.. When I select number 2, the combobox says 2, but when I leave the charm and return then it's empty again.. The binding should do that, isn't?

Comment: Have you tried changing the abstraction on `_testSpeed`?  Meaning, declaring it as 'public' instead of 'private'?

Answer (score 0):

In your situation  binding mode must be `OneWayToSource` like `SelectedValue="{Binding Path=TestSpeed, Mode=OneWayToSource}` . When TestSpeed is `string` or `int` that is work, when `short` - not work. I think you need to write specific converter for using `short` or using `int` and dont worry

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies. I tried to make it One Way and bind it like this way:

<ComboBox x:Name="cbTest" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=TestSpeed, Mode=OneWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,10,0,0" Width="250" SelectionChanged="cbTest_SelectionChanged"/>

But it's still not working..

Comment: I tried to make it to "int" and it's working now. I think I need to write a converter for using short yes. It seems that the net framework is not up to date with this I guess?

Comment: i really dont know, why short not converted by default as int or string.=)

Comment: Yes, maybe they do this to make it less popular and push people to use int and string ;D